# First Angular JS Plunk not working

Tags: angularjs

Please tell me why this very basic plunk is not working.

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/alQf2gACkYFSirjCzBFs?p=preview][1]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app>
<p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think there isn't any errors in this code.

Please explain me how to fix this.
Also let me know if anything needs to be known about Plunker.

Thanks for help.

Comment: see this : https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2
basic angularjs 1.3 setup

Answer (score 0):

Hi the plunk u created evrything is correct but the library for angular you mentioned have problem

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js
```

change to this

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js
```

thats it try.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
```

solved my problem for my basic angular JS application.